# Robust standard errors for negative binomial regression in R do not match those from Stata

Tags: r, stata, standards, standard-error, robust

I am replicating a negative binomial regression model in R. When calculating robust standard errors, the output does not match Stata output of standard errors.

The original Stata code is

```
nbreg displaced  eei lcostofwar cfughh roadskm lpopdensity ltkilled, robust nolog
```

I have attempted both manual calculation and `vcovHC` from `sandwich`. However, neither produces the same results.

My regression model is as follows:
`mod1 <- glm.nb(displaced ~ eei + costofwar_log + cfughh + roadskm + popdensity_log + tkilled_log, data = mod1_df)`

With `vcovHC` I have tried every option from `HC0` to `HC5`. 
Attempt 1:

```
cov_m1 <- vcovHC(mod1, type = "HC0", sandwich = T)
se <- sqrt(diag(cov_m1))
```

Attempt 2:

```
mod1_rob <- coeftest(mod1, vcovHC = vcov(mod1, type = "HC0"))
```

The most successful has been `HC0` and `vcov = sandwich` but no SEs are correct.

Any suggestions?

EDIT

My output is as follows (using `HC0`):

```
                 Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     1.3281183  1.5441312  0.8601  0.389730    
eei            -0.0435529  0.0183359 -2.3753  0.017536 *  
costofwar_log   0.2984376  0.1350518  2.2098  0.027119 *  
cfughh         -0.0380690  0.0130254 -2.9227  0.003470 ** 
roadskm         0.0020812  0.0010864  1.9156  0.055421 .  
popdensity_log -0.4661079  0.1748682 -2.6655  0.007688 ** 
tkilled_log     1.0949084  0.2159161  5.0710 3.958e-07 ***
```

The Stata output I am attempting to replicate is:

```
                 Estimate Std. Error    
(Intercept)     1.328     1.272
eei            -0.044     0.015 
costofwar_log   0.298     0.123  
cfughh         -0.038     0.018 
roadskm         0.002     0.0001   
popdensity_log -0.466     0.208 
tkilled_log     1.095     0.209
```

The dataset is found [here](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/TDHMNE) and the recoded variables are:

```
mod1_df <- table %>% 
  select(displaced, eei_01, costofwar, cfughh, roadskm, popdensity, 
tkilled)
mod1_df$popdensity_log <- log(mod1_df$popdensity + 1)
mod1_df$tkilled_log <- log(mod1_df$tkilled + 1)
mod1_df$costofwar_log <- log(mod1_df$costofwar + 1)
mod1_df$eei <- mod1_df$eei_01*100
```

Comment: Stata applies a degree of freedom correction that some R packages don't by default. That most likely causes the difference. As to your question; please include a minimal example and the Stata code you are running, othervise it is difficult for us to see what you are doing

Comment: would be great to see the exact regression command that produce the Stata table as well. And also provide a dataset which we can use

Answer (score 3):

Stata uses the observed Hessian for its computations, `glm.nb()` uses the expected Hessian. Therefore, the default `bread()` employed by the `sandwich()` function is different, leading to different results. There are other R packages that employ the observed hessian for its variance-covariance estimate (e.g., `gamlss`) but these do not supply an `estfun()` method for the `sandwich` package.

Hence, below I simply set up a dedicated `bread_obs()` function that extracts the ML estimates from a `negbin` object, sets up the negative log-likelihood, computes the observed Hessian numerically via `numDeriv::hessian()` and computes the "bread" from it (omitting the estimate for log(theta)):

```
bread_obs <- function(object, method = "BFGS", maxit = 5000, reltol = 1e-12, ...) {
  ## data and estimated parameters
  Y <- model.response(model.frame(object))
  X <- model.matrix(object)
  par <- c(coef(object), "log(theta)" = log(object$theta))

  ## dimensions
  n <- NROW(X)
  k <- length(par)

  ## nb log-likelihood
  nll <- function(par) suppressWarnings(-sum(dnbinom(Y,
    mu = as.vector(exp(X %*% head(par, -1))),
    size = exp(tail(par, 1)), log = TRUE)))

  ## covariance based on observed Hessian
  rval <- numDeriv::hessian(nll, par) 
  rval <- solve(rval) * n
  rval[-k, -k]
}
```

With that function I can compare the `sandwich()` output (based on the expected Hessian) with the output using the `bread_obs()` (based on the observed Hessian).

```
s_exp <- sandwich(mod1)
s_obs <- sandwich(mod1, bread = bread_obs)
cbind("Coef" = coef(mod1), "SE (Exp)" = sqrt(diag(s_exp)), "SE (Obs)" = sqrt(diag(s_obs)))
##                  Coef SE (Exp) SE (Obs)
## (Intercept)     1.328    1.259    1.259
## eei            -0.044    0.017    0.015
## costofwar_log   0.298    0.160    0.121
## cfughh         -0.038    0.015    0.018
## roadskm         0.002    0.001    0.001
## popdensity_log -0.466    0.135    0.207
## tkilled_log     1.095    0.179    0.208
```

This still has slight differences compared to Stata but these are likely numerical differences from the optimization etc.

If you create a new dedicated `bread()` method for `negbin` objects

```
bread.negbin <- bread_obs
```

then the method dispatch will use this if you do `sandwich(mod1)`.

Answer (score 2):

In R you need to manually provide a degree of freedom correction, so try this which I borrowed from [this source](http://www.richard-bluhm.com/clustered-ses-in-r-and-stata-2/):

```
dfa <- (G/(G - 1)) * (N - 1)/pm1$df.residual

# display with cluster VCE and df-adjustment
firm_c_vcov <- dfa * vcovHC(pm1, type = "HC0", cluster = "group", adjust = T)
coeftest(pm1, vcov = firm_c_vcov)
```

Here `G` is the number of Panels in your data set, `N` is the number of observations and `pm1` is your model estimated. Obviously, you could drop the clustering.

Comment: Thank you! However this did not work either, maybe because the data is not panel data.